# Difference between declaring in constructor and outside of constructor

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6

I'm using ES6, and Angular2. What is the difference between declaring something in the constructor like this:

```
class Example{
    constructor(private one: SomeClass, two: SomeClass){
        this.two = two;
    } 
}
```

and like this:

```
class Example2{
    private three:String = `What's the difference?`
}
```

I understand so far that if I import a class, then I *have* to declare it via the constructor. What is the difference between `one`, `two`, and `three` here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code in the constructor will be executed at the moment an instance of the object is created. Code in the class, but outside the constructor becomes class fields/memebers that are used by the class or can be called after an instance has been made.

In your example. `one` and `two` are the names of arguments that are expected to be **passed into the constructor** when the class is instantiated. Those values must be passed to the constructor.

`three`, on the other hand, is a class *"field"*. It is created by the class and used privately during the class' lifetime. It is not passed into the class.

So, for example, with this:

```
class Example{
    constructor(private one: SomeClass, two: SomeClass){
        this.two = two;
    } 
}
```

You would instantiate it like this:

```
var someClass1 = new SomeClass();
var someClass2 = new SomeClass();

var myExample = new Example(someClass1, someClass2);
```

But in this case:

```
class Example2{
    private three:String = `What's the difference?`
}
```

You would just instantiate is like this:

```
var myExample2 = new Example2();
```

Comment: Is `myExample` the same as how a constructor function works in ES5?

Comment: @userqwert Yes. You just have some syntactic sugar for it with ES6 and TypeScript.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Example{
    constructor(private one: SomeClass, two: SomeClass){
        this.two = two;
    } 
}
```

is shorthand syntax for

```
class Example{
    private one: SomeClass;
    constructor(one: SomeClass, two: SomeClass){
        this.one = one;
        this.two = two;
    } 
}
```

therefore if you have `private`, `protected`, or `public` before a constructor parameter, a class field is declared and initialized by the value passed to the constructor at once.

Comment: `one` is automatically declared because it has the `private` modifier. `two` won't be declared because it doesn't have such a modifier. If `this.two = two;` will cause an error depends on the compiler configuration.